# Confusing webpack/ES6 project setup

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I am trying to setup my first ES6 and webpack "application" and want to use classes and modules. But everytime I want to transpile the application via `webpack` command I get the following error:

```
$ webpack
Hash: c91db5651ec9123b8959
Version: webpack 3.5.6
Time: 2319ms
    Asset       Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
app.bundle.js     354 kB       0  [emitted]  [big]  main
   index.html  978 bytes          [emitted]
   [0] ./src/app.js 14 kB {0} [built]
    + 1 hidden module

ERROR in ./src/app.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'radar' in 'C:\dev\git\my-first-app\src'
 @ ./src/app.js 7:13-29
Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
     1 asset
       [0] ./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./src/index.html 1.37 kB {0} [built]
       [2] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 509 bytes {0} [built]
       [3] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 517 bytes {0} [built]
        + 1 hidden module
```

I have got the following files

package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-first-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "webpack.config.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "./node_modules/.bin/babel src -d dest",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server"
  }
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "webpack": "^3.5.6"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "d3": "3.5.17",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.28.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.5"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/app.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dest'),
        filename: 'app.bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                include: [
                    path.resolve(__dirname, "src")
                ],
                test: /\.js$/
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'src/index.html',
            filename: 'index.html',
            inject: 'body'
        })
    ]
};
```

src/app.js

```
'use strict';

import * as d3 from 'd3';
import radar from 'radar';

var r = new radar();
r.render();
```

radar.js

```
'use strict';

import * as d3 from 'd3';

export default class radar {
    render() { ... }
}
```

The index.html is some basic HTML file which contains just a empty document with head and body.

I think my error is somewhere in webpack.config.js or maybe I mixed different techniques to use ES6. Also the commands `npm build` does not help (it seems that nothing happens).
Can someone help me please? I am a bit confused and don't know what to look/search for...

Comment: Should `radar` be listed in your package.json's dependencies?

Comment: You're importing `'radar'` in `src/app.js`, but it's missing from your dependences in your `package.json`. Are you sure it's installed? Also, `npm build` is a built-in NPM command. If you want to run the script in your `package.json`, use `npm run build`.

Comment: Uhm... but radar is not an official package. I just wanted to import my own radar class (see radar.js). Do I also have to add each of my files as dependency?

Comment: Try `import Radar from '../radar';` or set a base URL of `'.'`;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`radar` is imported from `app.js`, but it is not in your `package.json` dependencies list.
You can run `npm install radar --save` from your command line to install the package and save a reference in your `package.json`

---

If radar is a local file, rather than a package, you will need to use a file path to import it. Like:

```
import radar from './path/to/file/radar';
```

Here is how import statements are resolved in Webpack - https://webpack.js.org/concepts/module-resolution/